# favicon does not show google search results on the phone

Tags: favicon

I have followed this test, the results show up. https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=www.baoholaodongtot.com But when searching on google on mobile devices does not show favicon

```
<link rel="icon" href="https://www.baoholaodongtot.com/templates/lam_tuong/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">

<link href="/templates/lam_tuong/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
```

Answer (score 0):

The site looks correct. Give Google some time to show your icon in its result pages. Depending of the popularity of your site, that could take days or even weeks.

As an additional clue, look at your site in the Google Search Console. For UX purpose, it displays your favicon, generally faster than the search engine. So if you see your new icon here, you can be optimistic.

Comment: Dear @philippe_b  I checked in Google Search Console. My website has not displayed favicon on google mobile for 5 months. This is the picture [link](https://ibb.co/ZfgQXTQ)

Comment: I've just googled "site:www.baoholaodongtot.com" and I do see your favicon in the result page. I used desktop Chrome and the mobile view of the Dev Tools to get a mobile page. As far as I can see, your issue is fixed!

Comment: thank you, i saw the icon on google search.